# Is it possible to add line to bash_profile via Node or a Shell script?

Tags: node.js

I have created a command line tool(`tool`) using nodejs. It uses Node's built in `debuglog` method multiple times across files. This means user of this tool can see helpful logs by setting `NODE_DEBUG=tool <tool> <fireCmd>`.

I wish all these logs print themselves when run `tool logs` without explicitly having to set `NODE_DEBUG` in current terminal session. I did some research and added `export NODE_DEBUG=tool` to my `.bash_profile`. It worked every terminal session.

**My failed tries:**

1. I tried to add `process.env.NODE_DEBUG=<tool>` to just after `use strict`. However, I assume `process.env` is spawning way before `NODE_DEBUG=<tool>` is attached. I am not even sure if it will work or my reasoning works.
2. I tried writing a shell script that will add `export NODE_DEBUG=<tool>` to the last line of `.bash_profile` with the intention running this script via nodejs `exec()` method. But all the forum showed me `export "your line" >> .bash_profile`. Not helpful.
3. I tried running the entire `NODE_DEBUG=tool <tool> <fireCmd>` using node's [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and throws following errorwhen server is supposed to started at a certain port :`{ Error: spawn NODE_DEBUG=tool ENOENT
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
     errno: 'ENOENT',
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'spawn NODE_DEBUG=tool',
     path: 'NODE_DEBUG=tool',
     spawnargs: [ 'tool', 'fireCmd' ] }` 
   `

No luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for the env option in the spawn command. Maybe you can post some of the code you used for attempt #3 above?

Comment: @BenSteward I don't know if I added enough code seeking help. Please let me know if you need more to it. Here is the link - https://jsfiddle.net/saif_shines/18ky9p4z/4/